# How to create Eclipse project based on web-source

Tags: java

How to create Eclipse project based on web-source, e.g. this one: http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source you linked is for an Eclipse project. You can simply import it into the IDE.

```
File->Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace
```

Quite obviously, you have to download the source from the website first. This works fine for me:

```
cd somedir
svn co http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/
```

Import into Eclipse from the folder you downloaded the source into.

Comment: If I select SVN->URL:http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer, then it says that there is some validation error.

Comment: What svn client are you using? I would recommend just downloading via command line if you can.

Comment: Error message: SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded...

Comment: If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

Comment: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.

Comment: @Klausos I've just installed the Subversive plugin on Eclipse. Restarted it (to solve the connector problem). Created a new project from SVN. And the code was downloaded to my workspace.

Comment: Not sure what client you're using - but you can grab the zip of the source [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32448398/jmapviewer.zip).

Answer (score 2):

1) The "jmapviewer" application you pointed out is a Java/Swing program.  It's not actually a "web program" - the source just happens to be available for the web.

2) In general, I'd suggest:

> a) Check out the complete project source to your filesystem (e.g.
>   over the web, with SVN)
>
> b) Create an Eclipse project of the appropriate type (here, a
>   Java/Swing project)
>
> c) Import the source from your filesystem into the project

3) In this case, however, it looks like it's *already* an Eclipse project.

Just import the project from Eclipse - it should be as easy as that!

Comment: "Just import the project from Eclipse - it should be as easy as that!". How to do this step by step? File->Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace...it does not allow to insert http link